# Help getting SSH server working again?

Tags: server, ssh, connection, pipe

I have a ubuntu desktop on my home network that I used to be able to ssh into from several different machines, but about a week ago it stopped working. The only thing that I can think of that I changed around that time was installing nordvpn on the host, but I have uninstalled it since then and it still isn't working. I have also tried sshing from my windows pc with putty but that didn't work either.

Here is the output from when I try to ssh on my Mac:

```
Drews-MBP-2:~ drewhalverson$ ssh drew@192.168.1.140
drew@192.168.1.140's password:
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```

And here is the output from checking the status on the ubuntu server:

```
Apr 30 11:40:41 Ubuntu-Server sshd[3963]: Accepted password for drew from 192.168.1.1 port 57585 ssh2
Apr 30 11:40:41 Ubuntu-Server sshd[3963]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user drew by (uid=0)
Apr 30 11:40:41 Ubuntu-Server sshd[3963]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user drew
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for me?